# Генерация случайной даты

Tags: perl

Всем привет. Понадобилось генерировать случайную дату от текущей до определенной.
В модуле Data::Random есть подобный функционал, но не работает жалуется на неверный диапазон

> max date is later than min date

Код идентичный примеру со страницы модуля на cpan

```
use Data::Random qw(:all);
my $date = rand_date( min => 'now', max => '2008-9-21' );
print $date;
```

Возможно есть какие нибудь альтернативные варианты? Модули?

Comment: Ошибка странная, поскольку максимальная дата и должна быть больше минимальной. Может, min date is later than max date? Тогда ошибка объяснима: ваша max data находится в прошлом, 9 лет назад из-за `now`. Попробуйте для теста минимальную дату указать точно и меньше, чем максимальная.

Comment: вы кажется перепутали min и max.вы же даете интервал из прошлого до текущей даты, значит max это как раз now, а min 2008 год

Comment: В модуле Data::Random описан данный функционал, мне нужно сгенерировать дату от сегодняшнего числа до любой даты в прошлом.

Answer (score -1):

Как бы там не выглядело сообщение об ошибке, сейчас явно не 2008 год, и появление ошибки логично. Поставьте max попозже. Вот такая строка у меня работает:

```
my $date = rand_date( min => 'now', max => '2020-9-21' );
```